# Replacing the JS confirm(...) box with a custom HTML one

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML button that goes to a page once it has been clicked and a JS confirmation button has been pressed:

```
<button onclick="return confirm("Are you sure?"); 
                 window.location="some_page.php" 
        type="button" class="btn">Some text
</button>
```

I want to replace the JS confirmation with a much nicer looking confirmation.  I want to use Twitter's bootstrap Javascript 'modal' library (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modal) to achieve this.  I already have the HTML written to be the confirmation box:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>Some title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <label for="something">Something</label>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input class="xlarge" id="something" size="30" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /clearfix -->
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input id="close" class="btn" type="button" value="Cancel" />
        <input id="close" class="btn primary" type="button" value="Done" />
    </div>
</div>
```

How to I get the `onclick` event to display my new popup rather than the standard JS confirmation?

Thanks so much :).

Answer (score 2):

I use the jQueryUI Dialog in place of the standard `confirm` option http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation

You specify your own buttons in the modal, so you can have "Are you sure?" with buttons "Yes" and "No"

Answer (score 1):

What about `window.showModalDialog` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either redefine `confirm`:

```
confirm = function(text,yes,no) {
    // show the modal window
    // set "yes" button to call yes()
    // set "no" button to call no()
}
```

Or what I did, which is to define a custom function and use that instead. I used `Confirm`, since JS is case-sensitive, but you can use anything.